# Getting 400 (Bad Request) on a POST request to Strapi

Tags: dart, post, http-status-code-400

I am trying to post data to my Strapi project from a Flutter app.
I made sure that the permissions are enabled for unauthenticated users.
What is wrong with my request?

```
Future saveReview(usrReview, usrRating) async {
  const endpoint = 'http://localhost:1337/api/reviews';
  var url = Uri.parse(endpoint);
  Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  };
  var reviewObj = jsonEncode({
    'review': usrReview,
    'rating': usrRating,
  });

  var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: headers,
    body: reviewObj,
  );

  print(response.statusCode); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the structure of reviewObj was missing something. I had to include 'data' in it for it to work. Here is what the correct body should look like.

```
 var reviewObj = jsonEncode({
  'data': {
    'review': usrReview,
    'rating': usrRating,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might fix you're problem! I recently ran into this same error a few days ago!

Basically you have to send the body of the POST request as a string.

Here's what it should look like!

```
Future saveReview(usrReview, usrRating) async {
  const endpoint = 'http://localhost:1337/api/reviews';

  var url = Uri.parse(endpoint);
  Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  };
  
  // Pass the JSON data as a whole string. Then the server should parse it
  var reviewObj = '{"review": $usrReview, "rating": $usrRating}';

  var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: headers,
    body: reviewObj,
  );

  print(response.statusCode);
}
```

Give that a try and let me know if that works!

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately I keep getting error 400